# Basic Authentication using Ruby200-x64, watir-webdriver for win 7 ie9 issue

Tags: internet-explorer, modal-dialog, watir-webdriver

OS Windows 7 64, IE 9.0, Ruby200-x64

Gems:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bson (1.8.6)
childprocess (0.3.9)
commonwatir (4.0.0)
ffi (1.8.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
mini_portile (0.5.0)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.7.3)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-update (2.0.3)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.32.1)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
watir (4.0.2)
watir-webdriver (0.6.4)
websocket (1.0.7)
win32-api (1.4.8)
win32-process (0.7.2)
windows-api (0.4.2)
windows-pr (1.2.2)
```

Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

app_url = "https://url"
@username = "ID"
@password = "password"

ch = Watir::Browser.new :ie

puts "Start test - GES Login/Add"
puts "Go to url: " + app_url
ch.goto app_url
sleep 2
```

I get

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/lib/selenium/w
ebdriver/remote/response.rb:52:in `assert_ok': Modal dialog present (Selenium::W
ebDriver::Error::UnhandledAlertError)
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:619:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:597:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:159:in `getCurrentUrl'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.32.1/l
ib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:120:in `current_url'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/w
atir-webdriver/browser.rb:111:in `url'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/w
atir-webdriver/browser.rb:80:in `goto'
        from example_login.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

I have tried every basic authentication example I can find out there and none seem to recognize the modal dialog box.
It is a simple Windows Security popup asking for the User Name and Password with a OK or Cancel button for windows basic auth.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in Firefox browser(If it not mandatory to test in ie), using Autoauth Add-on.

Invoke the Firefox profile in which you have installed Autoauth Add-on and that would do the basic authentication automatically.
You can find Autoauth in https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autoauth/

Comment: IE is the browser supported here at the County and therefore what I must test on.  All application use basic authentification in a moda dialog box. Thank you though.  I guess Watir will not work for my automation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the RAutomation gem - https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation

The gem can be used to automate window's windows. If you use watir-classic, it actually uses rautomation to perform some of the actions (ex saving files (if I recall correctly)). It is developed by the same developer as watir-classic so has the same intuitive api. Note that you can still use rautomation if you are using watir-webdriver (assuming you are running on windows).